# Django - Show multiple images

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to show all the image correlated to a chapter.
I cannot figure out what is wrong, base on what I found online it should work, but no images are display.

Only the outer div is coming out on html source.
By debugging the template I also notice that the for loop is taking all the chapters in the DB, not only the chapter I selected.
I think I need to restrict the ChapDetail view query somehow.

Can someone advise me on this two issue?

model.py

```
def image_dir_path(instance, filename):
    book = instance.chap.book.slug
    chapter = instance.chap.slug
    return os.path.join(book, chapter, str(uuid.uuid4().hex))


class Chapter(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
            settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            default=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    )
    book = models.ForeignKey(
            Book,
            related_name='chapters',
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            default=''
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=130, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('chap_detail')


class ShowImages(models.Model):
    chapter =models.ForeignKey(
            Chapter,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            default='',
            related_name="pics"
    )
    picture = models.FileField(upload_to=image_dir_path, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.picture.name
```

view.py

```
class ChapDetail(generic.ListView):
    model = Chapter
    template_name = 'chapters/chapter_detail.html'
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'chapters'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:book>', views.BookChaps.as_view(), name='chap_list'),
    path('<str:book>/<str:slug>/', views.ChapDetail.as_view(), name='chap_detail'), # both slug fields
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

template

```
<div style="padding-top: 10px; display: block;">
    {% for i in chapter.picture_set.all %}
        <div>
            <img src="{{ i.picture.url }}" alt="Not found">
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

media folder:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For restricting you query you can use the methode .filter() [Filter Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter)
It would be something along the line `Chapter.objects.filter(id=id)`.

You can get the id (or other filter param) from you path params in the url.

For the missing pictures, are you sure your MEDIA URL is set correct in the settings?

Comment: I'll try to setup the filter now, I added more info about media folder. I think is correct as it is.

Comment: I created the correct queryset returning an object_list of the chapter, but I'm still trying figuring out own to fix the template, for loop.